# react Hoc Component Decorator in Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I want a HOC Component as a Decorator do login check like this:

```
function Login() {
  return (Component) => {
    return class Login extends Component {
      componentDidMount() {
        console.log('doSometing')
        super.componentDidMount()
      }
      render () {
        return super.render()
      }
    }
  }
}

export default Login
```

```
import * as React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import withLogin from './login'

import logo from './logo.svg';

@withLogin()
class App extends React.Component {
  public render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          <h1 className="App-title">Welcome to React</h1>
        </header>
        <p className="App-intro">
          To get started, edit <code>src/App.tsx</code> and save to reload.
        </p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

But get Typescript error:

> (7,1): Unable to resolve signature of class decorator when called as
>   an expression.
>    Type 'typeof Login' is not assignable to type 'typeof
>   App'.
>       
> Type 'Login' is missing the following properties from type 'App': context, setState, forceUpdate, props, and 2 more.

Comment: https://repl.it/repls/TremendousLuckyDisc

Comment: link 404. and where is withLogin?

Comment: https://repl.it/@allenyang1/TremendousLuckyDisc

Answer (score 1):

The `Component` parameter conflicts with the `Component` import from the `react` package. It's better to rename the `Component` parameter to `WrappedComponent` to avoid variable name conflict.

Try:

```
import React from 'react';

function withLogin() {
  return (WrappedComponent: typeof React.Component) => {
    return class Login extends React.Component {
      componentDidMount() {
      }

      render() {
        return <WrappedComponent />;
      }
    };
  };
}

@withLogin()
class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App" />
    );
  }
}
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wG4AocgeirjWiIzogBMlzMBXAOw2Am5wA7sBgALADIQA5sG4AKAJRwA3uThwiMTlEHyA6lBRgwSFgGFckbkm4wAXHBgBPUxEyJiMAHSXwA2xhlAF4APlV1DU0kbV06ABsUAGckuClZQSQADxhbFlTkdB8-a0CIqKj6fxs7ABFgFgBZCB4YJXKKuABfSk7o7jYodrU+jS0dQQAeQ2NTCysAuzgqUIo+noqute6KHvIAARFxdLklcjRElLgAQRM4bNyBgq9fBZr4Ef7B4cixmIm4PJflFJixgAA3BLJJIAORQICQwQARLcwEjlqFgYptj09tRaIYBNJmGx8XAuLwYPxBEdJDJTso1DQouM4vISosgnAwhFmRVWYILtC0vTMjk8qkOe9ebQ+lVSnUGs1Wj8+Z09mr+XkkENGWTRtFYlMpWUVhRNVEehatvqdmSNbRDqI6RkzsyhVdUfdxU9PEVXtUykzZV8daqQ38jYDbRVQRCoSk4Qjkaj0SsY3BsbarbQukA)